# SQLiteNetExtensions - InsertWithChildrenAsync not working when Foreign Key constraint exists on child table

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms project, using SQLiteNetExtensions 2.0.0 and sqlite-net-pcl 1.5.231

I am trying to insert new records into a sqlite database.  My scenario works when I drop the NOT NULL and Foreign Key constraint on the child table.  When I re-add the constraints I get the following exception:

SQLite.SQLiteException: 'Constraint'

- Parent Model

```cs
[Table("RetailItem")]

public class RetailItemDTO

{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int RetailItemId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool Taxable { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public int RetailTypeId { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<RetailItemRetailerPriceDTO> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

- Child Model

```cs
[Table("RetailItemRetailerPrice")]

public class RetailItemRetailerPriceDTO

{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int RetailItemRetailerPriceId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(RetailItemDTO)), NotNull]
    public int RetailItemId { get; set; }

    public int RetailerId { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

- Insert/Update logic

```cs
public async Task Save(RetailItem entity)

{

    var dto = GetDTOFromBusinessModel(entity);

    if (dto.RetailItemId == 0)
    {
        await _sqliteRepository.Database.InsertWithChildrenAsync(dto, true);

        entity.Id = dto.RetailItemId;
    }
    else
        await _sqliteRepository.Database.InsertOrReplaceWithChildrenAsync(dto, true);
}
```

If I have an existing RetailItem, with a newly added price, the InsertOrReplaceWithChildrenAsync call <del>works without issue</del> fails with the following: SQLite.NotNullConstraintViolationException: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: RetailItemRetailerPrice.RetailItemId'

Anytime I add a new RetailItem with a new RetailItemRetailerPrice the Constraint exception occurs.

If I drop the NOT NULL and Foreign Key constraint for the RetailItemId on the RetailItemRetailerPrice table then both calls work.

I want to keep the proper constraints on my table.

Am I missing some attributes that will make my scenario work?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `RetailItemId`not null ,when you add a new item in `RetailItemRetailerPrice` table, you must set a `RetailItemId` for the new price.

`[ForeignKey(typeof(RetailItemDTO)), NotNull]
    public int RetailItemId { get; set; }`

If you do not want to keep the constraints on your table. Before you add a new item in `RetailItemRetailerPrice` table, you can query the `RetailItem` table, get the `RetailItemId`, In the end , you can add this new item in `RetailItemRetailerPrice` table.

Comment: If I remove the NotNull attribute from the property the Constraint error still occurs.  I didn't think I would need to lookup the RetailItemId after insert and manually update it on the child class.  I thought this framework would do that for me.  If I remove the NotNull and ForeignKey constraint on the RetailItemRetailerPrice table then the framework does insert the record with the correct RetailItemId, without me doing a lookup and setting the id on the class after the Parent record is inserted.